# How to make function using class (Common Lisp)

Tags: common-lisp

I need to make a function make-numbers which make an instance of class numbers:

```
(defclass numbers ()
  ((x :initform 0)
   (y :initform 0)))
```

Imput should be li this:`(make-numbers 2 8)`
I started: `(defun make-numbers (new-x new-y) (....`, but I don't know how continue. I Have tried it all the day, no result. Finally, I need to count this two numbers.

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you add `:initarg` keywords for your slots:

```
(defclass numbers ()
  ((x :initform 0 :initarg :x)
   (y :initform 0 :initarg :y)))
```

Then invoke [make-instance](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ins.htm) from your function:

```
(defun make-numbers (new-x new-y)
  (make-instance 'numbers :x new-x :y new-y))
```

That way, you won't have to use `setf` on [slot-value](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_slt_va.htm) to initialize the slots of your instance.

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar, but it didn't work. I wrote bad code with `setf` and `slot-value`.